# How can you retrieve webpages based on URLs and convert each to a beautifulsoup object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am scraping a [website](https://jammer.ie/used-cars) I was able to get all the information thanks to Andrej Kesely, I was also able to syntheses URLs that downloaded the first 50 pages, however now I want to retrieve the webpages based on the URLs and convert them into a beautifulsoup and I also want to retrieve all the information and the URL(href) to access the detailed car information.
I am new to python and website scraping so I really don't know where to start but here is the code for that syntheses the first 50 pages of the website

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
for i in range(1, 50):
    response = requests.get(f"https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={i}&per-page=12")
    with open(f"example{i}.html", "w" , encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        fp.write(response.text)

urls = []
prices = []
makes = []

# for loop index by i
with open(f"example{i}.html", "r") as fp:
    webpage = fp.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "span-9 right-col"})

len(tables[0].contents)


for it in tables[0].contents[1:]:
    if it == "\n":
        continue
    for jt in it.findall('div', class_="col-lg-4 col-md-12 car-listing"):
        price = jt.find('p', class_="price").text
        make = jt.find('h6', class_="car-make").text
        url = f"https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={i}&per-page=12"
        urls.append(url)
        prices
```

I know I must make a beautifulsoup object but I really don't know what to do if you could please explain what to do it would be great thanks

I want to have it where I'm able to
Retrieve the webpages based on these URLs and convert each into a beautifulsoup object and
Retrieve Car Manufacturing Year, Engine, Price, Dealer information (if it is available), and the URL (href) to access the detailed car information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over multiple pages you can do:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={}&per-page=12"

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).text, "html.parser")

    for car in soup.select(".car"):
        info = car.select_one(".top-info").get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
        make, model, year, price = info.split("|")
        dealer_name = car.select_one(".dealer-name h6").get_text(
            strip=True, separator=" "
        )
        address = car.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True)

        features = {}
        for feature in car.select(".car--features li"):
            k = feature.img["src"].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
            v = feature.span.text
            features[f"feature_{k}"] = v

        all_data.append(
            {
                "make": make,
                "model": model,
                "year": year,
                "price": price,
                "dealer_name": dealer_name,
                "address": address,
                "url": "https://jammer.ie"
                + car.select_one("a[href*=vehicle]")["href"],
                **features,
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
# prints sample data to screen:
print(df.tail().to_markdown(index=False))
# saves all data to CSV
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

| make | model | year | price | dealer_name | address | url | feature_speed | feature_engine | feature_transmission | feature_owner | feature_door-icon1 | feature_petrol5 | feature_paint | feature_hatchback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Skoda | Fabia | 2014 | €7,500 | Blue Diamond Cars | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/165691-skoda-fabia-2014 | 128627 miles | 1.2 litres | Manual | 2 previous owners | 4 doors | Petrol | Beige | Estate |
| Ford | Kuga | 2016 | €16,750 | Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/165690-ford-kuga-2016 | 99000 miles | 2.0 litres | Manual | 1 previous owners | 5 doors | Diesel | Grey | MPV |
| Hyundai | i40 | 2015 | Price on application | Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/165689-hyundai-i40-2015 | 98000 miles | 1.7 litres | Manual | 1 previous owners | 5 doors | Diesel | Black | Estate |
| Dacia | Sandero | 2016 | €9,950 | Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/165688-dacia-sandero-2016 | 43000 miles | nan | Manual | 3 previous owners | 4 doors | Petrol | Blue | Hatchback |
| Ford | Fiesta | 2016 | Price on application | Ballincollig Motor Company / Trident | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/165687-ford-fiesta-2016 | 45000 miles | 1.0 litres | Manual | 2 previous owners | 5 doors | Petrol | Silver | Hatchback |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: so does this do both of the things I want to do? or does it just I want to retrieve the webpages based on the URLs and convert them into a beautifulsoup object?